# Remove sharp or jagged edges in mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, sculpting

The problematic edges are small, convex, sharp protrusions on a larger concave, smooth surface.  Edge split, smooth, and subdivision modifiers do not achieve the smooth surface I'm looking for.  Is there a way to force edges with larger than, say 290 degrees to become less obtuse?  Note that I describe the edge this way because that is the side of the surface I'll be viewing (not side of the surface with the equivalent acute angle).  Here's an example:

[image]

The mostly horizontal lines are where thin, jagged protrude out of the otherwise smooth surface.  Close-up:

[image]

Using the *Smooth* brush in sculpt mode with dynamic topology and *Collapse short edge* enabled gives (applied on various scales for demonstration):

[image]

This is close but is there a way to now make the 'crumpled'-looking surface become more like the other smooth surface?

Comment: It looks to me like the faces on the other side of the mesh are intersecting. Are you looking for a way to fix this with sculpting?

Comment: @gandalf3-- I've updated the close-up so you can see that the larger, concave, smooth surface is bridged by regularly repeating smaller convex features.  A solution by sculpting or modifiers works

Comment: You could try going over them with the *Smooth* brush in sculpt mode (with dynamic topology and *Collapse short edge* enabled)

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks! This very well may be a solution. Please let me test extensively real quick

Comment: @gandalf3-- Almost but can we take it a step further to smooth crumpling? (see edit)

Comment: you could try a smooth modifier and maybe some subsurf. If I was correct and the mesh has thickness and the edges were caused by the other side intersecting, (It's hard to tell from the screenshots) an alternative to trying to model both sides is to use a *solidify modifier*.

Comment: Another thing that could help is a [*Remesh* modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.62/Remesh_Modifier).

Comment: Wow, the Remesh Modifier let's me make a Lego Suzie!! Problem is that it's desirable to have few verts where there's less detail and large curves and more detail on creases and sharp corners. Remesh makes a very dense mesh. But the Blocks option is so cool. Thank's for mentioning it.

Comment: @Haunt_House I often add a [*Decimate*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Decimate) modifier after a remesh to try to reduce density. (the wiki is a bit out of date, there is now an *un-subdivide* option, as well as a *planar* option which is actually the same as *Limited dissolve*.

Answer (score 5):

This topology is so messed up (current *Sculpt Mode* will do that), it might need a [retopology](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Retopo).

Either use a [*Shrinkwrap Modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Deform/Shrinkwrap) to get a clean result with a new mesh and far less verts (after the rough adjustments, you can enable the modifier to be active during *Edit Mode* which glues your verts to the surface) or use use the [*Bsurfaces*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev%3aRef/Release_Notes/2.64/Bsurfaces_1.5) addon. With it, you can convert [*Grease Pencil*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Sketching) strokes into topology. You need to set the grease pencil to *Surface* or otherwise the strokes won't connect to the underlying mesh.

Comment: You might want to add surface snapping to your list

Comment: Surface Snapping? What witchcraft is this?

Comment: @Haunt_House Surface snapping equals the combination of snapping to face with projection to other objects enabled (all connected to the magnet icon in 3DView header). Basically the same effect as the shrinkwrap modifier but applied to each vertex you move while in edit mode.

Comment: @Haunt_House see the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Snap_to_Mesh#Snap_Element). (it's actually called *Face* snapping, not surface snapping :P)

Comment: Already found it, tried it, didn't like it. The fact that only one vert at a time is affected means I have to select every single vert. The shrinkwrap seems to be more convenient so far.

Comment: @Haunt_House Yes, that is annoying.. I was actually going to ask if there was a way around that a while ago, but now I don't need to :) (the Shrinkwrap works beautifully)

Comment: @Haunt_House - snapping actually applies to all selected verts, you can select as many verts as you want and press G and click to have them all snap to the surface. It's only g,s,r that snap, other operators like subdivide ignore snapping. The difference would be that snapping moves from current location to the surface right below based on viewing angle, where shrinkwrap scales the object down until it hits the nearest surface.